Use kubernetes secrets as jenkins credentials without a respin
I'm looking for a way to use kubernetes secrets in my jenkins helm release and be able to update/add credentials without having to respin the instance. Currently it works when using plain text and can be updated while jenkins is running. But once using secrets it causes the instance to respin which is undesirable. There are plugins like hashicorp vault which could be used or just using basic plain text, but having the credentials hidden within the pod and within git is important.
Any ideas are welcomed, thanks.
Please note this is not related to how I can use them in my Jenkins pipeline, but how I can have them setup as credentials on my instance.
Currently I use the credentials: option in the helm release as well as this additionalExistingSecrets:, this seems to be the only way I can get the secret in as a credential working.
